# Firebase, Flutter, Provider - Mapping, and Using Data via Provider

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm new to flutter and firebase (and yes i know this question has been asked before).
But i've seen plenty of different ways to map firebase data into provider, and some reason cannot get a single to work.
I have this data structure. And all i wish, is to Map it into an class / object.

[Firebase screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzqJh.png)

This is my data model.dart:

```
@immutable
class Requests {
  Requests({
    this.name = '',
    this.pairingId = 0,
  });

  final String name;
  final double pairingId;

  Requests.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)
      : this(
          name: json['name']! as String,
          pairingId: json['pairingId'] as double,
        );

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'pairingId': pairingId,
    };
  }
}

@immutable
class UserDataTest with ChangeNotifier {
  UserDataTest({
    this.firstName = '',
    this.lastName = '',
    this.gender = '',
    this.dateOfBirth,
    this.userUID = '',
    this.uidp = '',
    this.pairingId = 0,
    this.requests = const [],
  });

  UserDataTest.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)
      : this(
          firstName: json['firstName']! as String,
          lastName: json['lastName']! as String,
          gender: json['gender']! as dynamic,
          dateOfBirth: json['dateOfBirth']! as DateTime?,
          userUID: json['userUID']! as String,
          uidp: json['uidp']! as String,
          pairingId: json['pairingId']! as double,
          requests: json['requests']! as List<Requests>,
        );

  late final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final dynamic gender;
  final DateTime? dateOfBirth;
  final String userUID;
  final String uidp;
  final double pairingId;
  final List<Requests> requests;

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() {
    return {
      'firstName': firstName,
      'lastName': lastName,
      'gender': gender,
      'dateOfBirth': dateOfBirth,
      'userUID': userUID,
      'uidp': uidp,
      'pairingId': pairingId,
      'requests': requests,
    };
  }
}
```

But from here i dont have any solution that works just partly.
Again, my wish is to be able to just write, ex. user.firstName and display the first Name. How do i get to there?
I know im missing the call to firebase, but i haven't been successful in making one.
I dont know if have to do something inside the provider.
(Yes i have a multiprovider at the top of my tree
and a call to the provider where im using it or wanting to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion: start over. Just start by creating a simple class manually with just a few of the fields from Firebase, and work your way out. For example use the **UserDataTest** and just make it a class:

```dart
class UserDataTest {
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;

  UserDataTest({ this.firstName, this.lastName });

  factory UserDataTest.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   return UserDataTest(
     firstName: json['firstName'],
     lastName: json['lastName'],
   );
  }
}
```

Try to keep these classes as plain as possible. Create other classes for your services and then make those extend **ChangeNotifier**, like to encapsulate your business logic and trigger notifications.

Then, from Firebase you will easily be able to do stuff like:

```dart
List<UserDataTest> userData = [];
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userdata').get().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  userData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => UserDataTest.fromJson(doc.data())).toList();
});
```

My two cents.